# intercepting internet calls android

Tags: java, android, http, http-post, android-wifi

i want to create an app that intercepts a HttpPost call to a website, logs all the header info. There will be a java application on a computer that uses adb logcat to identify the header info make the call and then sends the result as data in a broadcast intent to then be used on the device.

i understand how to do this using the adb so that it would only work with my applications (using alternatives to standard connection libraries), but dont know what classes/methods to overwrite/extend to make it appear as a internet connection, enabling it to work with any application.

my intention is to end up with something similar to the internet pass-through setting on htc devices, ideally running on a raspberry pi.

possibly doing this by creating a "fake" wifi connection in wifi manager and using that.